# How to delete data from Firebase after X amount of time

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am currently developing an application and I have created data on Firebase Realtime Database. I am not sure how after x amount of time I can delete specific data in Firebase RelatimeDatabase. My first approach was to use the java.util.TimerTask() but then when I was testing it I found out this is only when the application is running. I would need something that works in the background constantly. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

the attempt I made so far was simply calling a log statement to see if it executes every x amount of time but then I realised I would need this to run constantly like a background service.

```
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    resetDatabase();
                }
            },
            10000
    );
```

Comment: use a [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

Comment: thanks I will look into this